# Помогите с ошибкой "Нельзя преобразовать тип string к integer"

Tags: pascal

```
    Program abc; 
var
m: integer;
d, count: byte;
var 
cs1,cs2,res,change:integer; 
TD:string; 
{функция перевода Dec числа в любую сс} 
function FromDec(n,r:longint):string; 
var 
s:String; 
const 
digit:string[9]='012345678'; 
begin 
s:=''; 
repeat 
s:=digit[(n mod r)+1]+s; 
n:=n div r; 
until n=0; 
FromDec:=s; 
end; 
{фунция перевода любой сс в Dec} 
function ToDec(n:string;r:longint):longint; 
var 
m,i:longint; 
const 
digit:string[9]='012345678'; 
begin 
m:=0; 
while n[1]='0' do 
delete(n,1,1); 
for i:=1 to length(n) do 
m:=m*r+pos(n[i],digit)-1; 
ToDec:=m; 
end; 
{осоновная программы} 
begin 
writeln('Введите из какой CC:'); 
repeat 
readln(cs1); 
until 
(cs1>=2) and (cs1<=9); 
writeln('Введите число в соответствии с CC:'); 
readln(TD); 
writeln('Введите в какую CC:'); 
repeat 
readln(cs2); 
until 
(cs2>=2) and (cs2<=36); 
writeln('Перевод из ',cs1,' CC —> ',cs2,' CC:'); 
writeln(FromDec(ToDec(TD,cs1),cs2)); 
begin {Счетчик количества определенной цифры в числе}
m:=FromDec(ToDec(TD,cs1),cs2);
write('Цифра: ');
readln(d);
count := 0;
writeln(m);
       while m > 0 do begin
        if m mod 10 = d then 
            count := count + 1;
        m := m div 10;
    end;
writeln('Количество цифр: ', count);
end;
end.
```

Ошибка: Project2.pas(53) : Нельзя преобразовать тип string к integer

Comment: Ну разумеется: нельзя в целочисленную переменную записывать строку.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что делать

Comment: Вот почему учат не на python?

Comment: @drmzbr не присваивайте числу строку ;-)

Comment: В школе дали олимпиаду

Comment: @vp_arth, потому что питон никому не нужен

Comment: Но мне надо получить значение, чтобы потом узнать кол-во определенных числе в нем

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Так как разрешить ошибку ?

Comment: FromDec у тебя возвращает string, а присваиваешь это значение ты переменной `m` у которой тип integer. Либо присваивай другой переменной либо делай так чтобы функция тоже integer возвращала, либо конвертируй из строки в число

Comment: @Grundy Project2.pas(55) : Нет перегруженной подпрограммы с таким количеством параметров Val
    VAL(FromDec(ToDec(TD,cs1),cs2),m);

Comment: не знаю что это за строка, и что ты тут пытаешь сделать

Comment: @Grundy В строковую переменную можно записывать не только буквы, но и цифры. Однако это будут не числа, как таковые, а их символьное представление. Для преобразования символьных представлений числа в само число, и наоборот, используются процедуры STR и VAl.

Comment: допустим, и? Что ты тут пытаешься сделать? Ты посмотри какие параметры принимают эти процедуры и что передаешь им ты

Comment: @Grundy Конвертировать srtring в integer

Comment: _посмотри какие параметры принимают эти процедуры и что передаешь им ты_

Comment: @Grundy Ничего. VAL (z; var a; var CODE: integer); - Project2.pas(58) : Встречено ';', а ожидалось ')'